# How to seed my development database with rails test fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to seed my development database in exactly the same way as I seed my test database. I have a `PersonalTitle` model that has one attribute, `title`. The `title` has values like `Mr`, `Mrs`, `Miss`, `Ms` and `Dr`. There are several other models that `belong_to` `PersonalTitle`. For example

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :personal_title
end

class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :personal_title
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :personal_title
end
```

... and so forth

In `personal_titles.yml` that seeds the test database, I have

```
personal_title_mr:
  title: Mr
personal_title_mrs:
  title: Mrs
personal_title_ms:
  title: Ms
personal_title_miss:
  title: Miss
personal_title_dr:
  title: Dr
```

and then if I want to use a personal title in `administrators.yml` I have

```
administrator_john_smith:
  personal_title: personal_title_mr
```

So I can use named references to populate the administrators table with the personal_title_id. I can't do that if I seed my development database. From what I found on stack overflow, for development, `personal_titles.yml` has to look like this,

```
- title: Mr
- title: Mrs
- title: Ms
- title: Miss
- title: Dr
```

So the personal titles can't be named in a yml file that is used to populate a development database. Why not? Rails knows how to use names references because it does it when the test database is seeded.

I'm using Rails 4.10 and Ruby 1.9.3

**Update**

I am seeding my development database with `db\seeds\seed_all.rb`. Inside this file I have

```
seed_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', 'personal_titles.yml')
personal_titles = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
PersonalTitle.create!(personal_titles)
```

I know about faker and I have a seed file for it. In the case above I want known data that I understand, that doesn't change and where I have full control over the associations.

Comment: I don't fully get your issue, because you interact with seeds and fixtures like the same (while I think about different things), but environment usually never influence any processes to make it so different. Left my answer with some common ideas

Comment: Have you tried `rake db:fixtures:load`?

Comment: No I haven't @MrYoshiji , but I just did and that's exactly what I wanted. If you add a formal answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can trigger the load of your fixtures in your database by using the following rake command:

```
rake db:fixtures:load
```

By default, the rails env will be development so the fixtures will load in this environment's database.

Comment: Note that it will clear the data in development db first

Answer (score 0):

To seed your database I would go with `db/seeds.rb` which accept just usual ruby code. In tests database is usually get populated with `fixtures` (I think you are using this approach) or with `factory_girl`, but I haven't faced similar cases of seeding dev in the same way.

In case you have complicated and long seed file, look into some gems for seed database. I used `seedbank` in one of my latest project to split seeds into separate files like `seeds/users.seeds.rb`, `seeds/categories.seeds.rb`, etc